# You can reverse the creation of an LVM partition on top of Windows partition

Tags: partitioning, windows-10, lvm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVbrP.jpg)I wanted to install Ubuntu in dual boot with two Windows 10 that I had installed for different uses, but accidentally select the options of: 'Erase disk and install Ubuntu' + 'Use LVM with the new Ubuntu. When I saw the popup warning I immediately cancel, but the LVM is still set.

I can't boot into Windows. Is there any way to roll back LVM partition to recover Windows partition?

Comment: Welcome! We ask and answer questions here in English. **Please edit & translate** your question or remove it.

Comment: Hola Wilfredo... mientras traduces la pregunta.... si ya escribió la nueva configuración en el disco, es muy dificil revertirlo... Inicia desde un ubuntu live y postea que ve el programa gparted para tener una idea de como quedó el disco.

Comment: Ok gracias jpbrain, ya hago lo que me dices.                Ok thanks jpbrain, I already do what you tell me.

Comment: No, this is an irreversible mistake. You should restore from backups and you will need to reinstall the operating system(s).  If for some reason your backups are deficient, stop using the device right away until you can make a bit-for-bit copy. Any further use can exacerbate data loss.  Once a copy is made, you might be able to recover some files with recovery software like testdisk or photorec.  These are advanced tools and may not be able to recover data

Comment: @jpbrain Following your recommendation, I already have the gparted image, but I don't know how to attach it.------       Siguiendo tu recomendación, ya tengo la imagen gparted, pero no sé cómo adjuntarla.

Comment: So. What partitions do you see on the disk? To attach the image edit your question and click on the image icon.

Comment: @jpbrain Place the image, can you see it?  ----  coloque la imagen, la puedes ver?

Comment: Sorry. Seems that old disk is gone two partitions writen. No options to go back.

Comment: @Nmath Would those programs run from the ubuntu LiveCD?

Comment: @jpbrain Could I recover my data with the programs indicated by Nmath? Or do you know a better one?

Comment: You should try. You will only loose time if it does not work. Testdisk is for Linux. Boot from Ubunut live and follow this link. https://vitux.com/how-to-recover-deleted-files-in-ubuntu-through-testdisk/